# Проблемы с отображением графиков matplotlib в окне PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, matplotlib

В окне нужно отображать разные типы графиков, в зависимости от выбранной даты (или диапазона дат) и radiobutton'ов. Если сначала отображать графики "ЧС по часам" и "ЧС в диапазоне дат", то сами графики занимает весь холст. Если же нарисовать график "Матрица ошибок", то построение вышеуказанных графиков изменится и график будет занимать область в зависимости от данных, которые взяты из БД, а не весь холст. Пример:

**Если не рисовать матрицу ошибок**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Сама матрица ошибок**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Вид графиков после матрицы ошибок**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Метод, который рисует графики и добавляет их в layout:

```
def graphic(self):
    self.sc.axes.clear()
    con = sqlite3.connect(DB_FILE_NAME)
    result = {}
    # Матрица ошибок
    if self.radio_pos_neg.isChecked():
        data = np.array(con.cursor().execute('''SELECT predicted_value, actual_value FROM PredictedMessages
                                        WHERE actual_value IS NOT NULL''').fetchall())
        y_test = data[:, 0]
        yhat = data[:, 1]
        cnf_matrix = confusion_matrix(y_test, yhat, labels=[1, 0])
        np.set_printoptions(precision=2)
        self.sc.plot_confusion_matrix(cnf_matrix, classes=['Чрезвычайная ситуация', 'Обычные сообщения'], normalize=False,
                              title='Матрица ошибок')
    # ЧС в конкретный день по часам
    elif self.dt_begin.dateTime() == self.dt_end.dateTime():
        date = self.calendarWidget.selectedDate()
        date = f'{date.year()}-{str(date.month()).rjust(2, "0")}-{str(date.day()).rjust(2, "0")}'
        data = con.cursor().execute(f'''SELECT date, predicted_value FROM PredictedMessages
                                    WHERE date LIKE "{date}%"''').fetchall()
        result = {str(key).rjust(2, '0'): 0 for key in range(24)}
        for item in data:
            hour = item[0].split()[1].split(':')[0]
            result[hour] += 1
        self.sc.axes.plot(list(result.keys()), list(result.values()))
        self.sc.axes.set_title('Количество ЧС по часам', fontsize=12)
        self.sc.axes.set_xlabel('Часы', fontsize=10)
        self.sc.axes.set_ylabel('Количество ЧС', fontsize=10)
    # ЧС в диапазоне дат
    else:
        begin = self.dt_begin.dateTime().toString('yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss')
        end = self.dt_end.dateTime().toString('yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss')
        data = con.cursor().execute('''SELECT date, predicted_value FROM PredictedMessages
                                    WHERE date BETWEEN ? AND ?''',
                                    (begin, end)).fetchall()
        for item in data:
            date = item[0][:10]
            result[date] = result.get(date, 0) + item[1]
        self.sc.axes.bar(list(result.keys()), list(result.values()))
        self.sc.axes.set_title('Количество ЧС по дням', fontsize=12)
        self.sc.axes.set_xlabel('День', fontsize=10)
        self.sc.axes.set_ylabel('Количество ЧС', fontsize=10)
    self.sc.figure.tight_layout()
    self.layout_for_graph.addWidget(self.sc)
    self.sc.draw()
```

Класс для встраивания графиков и настройки для матрицы ошибок:

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import itertools


class MplCanvas(FigureCanvasQTAgg):
    def __init__(self, fig):
        self.fig = fig
        self.axes = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
        super(MplCanvas, self).__init__(self.fig)

    def plot_confusion_matrix(self, cm, classes,
                              normalize=False,
                              title='Confusion matrix',
                              cmap=plt.get_cmap('Blues')):
        self.axes.imshow(cm, interpolation='nearest', cmap=cmap)
        self.axes.set_title(title, fontsize=12)
        tick_marks = np.arange(len(classes))
        self.axes.set_xticks(tick_marks)
        self.axes.set_yticks(tick_marks)
        self.axes.set_xticklabels(classes, fontsize=10)
        self.axes.set_yticklabels(classes, fontsize=10)
        thresh = cm.max() / 2.
        for i, j in itertools.product(range(cm.shape[0]), range(cm.shape[1])):
            self.axes.text(j, i, format(cm[i, j]),
                           horizontalalignment="center",
                           color="white" if cm[i, j] > thresh else "black")
```

**UPDATE**
Минимальный воспроизводимый пример.

*Класс для рисования графиков*

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
import numpy as np
from Charts import MplCanvas
import sys
from ui import Ui_MainWindow


class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5, 4), dpi=100, tight_layout=True)
        self.sc = MplCanvas(self.fig)
        self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.sc, self)
        self.layout_for_graph.addWidget(self.toolbar)
        self.layout_for_graph.addWidget(self.sc)
        self.btn_plot.clicked.connect(self.graphic)
        self.btn_matrix.clicked.connect(self.graphic)

    def graphic(self):
        self.sc.axes.clear()
        # Матрица ошибок
        if self.sender().text() == 'Матрица ошибок':
            y_test = [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
                      0, 1, 1, 1]
            yhat = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
                      0, 1, 1, 1]
            cnf_matrix = confusion_matrix(y_test, yhat, labels=[1, 0])
            np.set_printoptions(precision=2)
            self.sc.plot_confusion_matrix(cnf_matrix, classes=['Чрезвычайная ситуация', 'Обычные сообщения'],
                                          normalize=False,
                                          title='Матрица ошибок')
        # ЧС по дням
        else:
            dates = ['18-05-2021', '19-05-2021', '20-05-2021', '21-05-2021']
            values = [5, 2, 1, 7]
            self.sc.axes.bar(dates, values)
            self.sc.axes.set_title('Количество ЧС по дням', fontsize=12)
            self.sc.axes.set_xlabel('День', fontsize=10)
            self.sc.axes.set_ylabel('Количество ЧС', fontsize=10)
        self.sc.figure.tight_layout()
        self.layout_for_graph.addWidget(self.sc)
        self.sc.draw()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

*Класс для встраивания графиков в PyQt*

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import itertools


class MplCanvas(FigureCanvasQTAgg):
    def __init__(self, fig):
        self.fig = fig
        self.axes = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
        super(MplCanvas, self).__init__(self.fig)

    def plot_confusion_matrix(self, cm, classes,
                              normalize=False,
                              title='Confusion matrix',
                              cmap=plt.get_cmap('Blues')):
        self.axes.imshow(cm, interpolation='nearest', cmap=cmap)
        self.axes.set_title(title, fontsize=12)
        tick_marks = np.arange(len(classes))
        self.axes.set_xticks(tick_marks)
        self.axes.set_yticks(tick_marks)
        self.axes.set_xticklabels(classes, fontsize=10)
        self.axes.set_yticklabels(classes, fontsize=10)
        thresh = cm.max() / 2.
        for i, j in itertools.product(range(cm.shape[0]), range(cm.shape[1])):
            self.axes.text(j, i, format(cm[i, j]),
                           horizontalalignment="center",
                           color="white" if cm[i, j] > thresh else "black")
```

*Интерфейс, созданный в Qt Designer:*

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(870, 693)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.btn_matrix = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_matrix.setObjectName("btn_matrix")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.btn_matrix, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.btn_plot = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_plot.setObjectName("btn_plot")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.btn_plot, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.layout_for_graph = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout_for_graph.setObjectName("layout_for_graph")
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.layout_for_graph, 0, 0, 1, 2)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.btn_matrix.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Матрица ошибок"))
        self.btn_plot.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ЧС по часам"))
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Comment: @S.Nick Добавил пример

Comment: Все графики вы рисуете на объекте `sc.axes`, а матрицу ошибок - напрямую в `sc`: `self.sc.plot_confusion_matrix`. Добавьте `ax=self.sc.axes` в вызов `plot_confusion_matrix`, чтобы переиспользовать существующий объект `Axes`

Comment: @PakUula, извините, но я не совсем понял ваш ответ. self.sc - экземпляр класса MplCanvas, который в качестве атрибутов имеет axes. При вызове функции self.sc.plot_confusion_matrix, в неё передаётся этот экземпляр, а уже там рисуется график на осях self.axes, которые были определены в конструкторе класса MplCanvas. Т.е., обращение к осям внутри метода plot_confusion matrix через self.axes, равносильно обращение к осям извне через self.sc.axes. Или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: Я увидел в документации, что `plit_confusion_matrix` создаёт новый объект `figure` и соответственно новые оси. Попробуйте и скажите, что получилось.

Comment: @PakUula, во-первых, такого метода нет в документации matplotlib, это реализация imshow, просто с подписями. Это можно увидеть в классе для встраивания графиков, там написан этот метод. И конечно, я сначала проверил то, что вы мне написали, но это не сработало.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Спасибо, что дали пример. С ним получилось разобраться.

Barplot вытягивается вверх после того, как у объекта `self.sc.axes` выставляется параметр `aspect` в 1.0. По оси `x` координата меняется от -0.6 до 3.6, а по оси y от 0 до 9, поэтому график получается вытянутым вверх.

Чтобы график занимал всю площадь фигуры достаточно сбрасывать отношение осей после очистки графика:

```
    def graphic(self):
        self.sc.axes.clear()
        self.sc.axes.set_aspect('auto')
        # ...
```

Протестировано на вашем примере - работает.

Comment: Действительно, теперь всё работает. Огромное вам спасибо, вы мне очень помогли!